# Use of "parent" column in subselect

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Let's say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE partners (name varchar, id int, hire_date varchar);
CREATE TABLE payments (partner_id int, payment_date varchar, payment_amount decimal);
```

and I want to create a query that says "Give me the name of all the partners, and a sum of all payments made to them after their hire date."

I might try something like this:

```
SELECT name, subselect.pps FROM partners 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT partner_id, sum(payment_amount) AS pps 
    FROM payments WHERE payment_date > partners.hire_date) subselect 
    ON subselect.partner_id=partners.id
;
```

But of course I get:

```
no such column: partners.hire_date
```

Is there any way I can do this, i.e. use a column from the outer query in my inner query?

Comment: Why the hate?  This is a legit question, no?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use an `OUTER JOIN` without the subquery:

```
SELECT part.name, SUM(pay.payment_amount) pps
FROM partners part
    LEFT JOIN payments pay ON part.id = pay.partner_id 
        AND pay.payment_date > part.hire_date
GROUP BY part.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a subquery, you cannot use a subquery that is joined to `partners` *later*.

A correlated subquery must be a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT sum(payment_amount)
        FROM payments
        WHERE partner_id   = partners.id
          AND payment_date > partners.hire_date
       ) AS pps
FROM partners
```